# My program is ignoring my if statement and goes straight to the else

Tags: java, string, if-statement

```
String firstanswer = scan.nextLine();
    if(firstanswer == answer2)
        {
            System.out.println("OK lets get started");
            }
    else
        {
            System.out.println("That is incorrect, of course you want to play");
            }
```

//answer2 is set to "yes", i declared it above

Comment: By the way, don't assume that your `if` statement is being ignored just because only your `else` is executing.  Simply setting a breakpoint at the `if` statement would have shown you what was going on.

Comment: Each time I see `==` instead of `equals`... it ruin my day.

Answer (score 7):

make it `firstanswer.equals(answer2)` instead of `firstanswer == answer2`.

When you want to check for equality of `String` in java then use [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method instead of `==` operator.

- [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method checks whether the contents of `String` objects are same
- `==` operator checks whether both the reference variables refer to same `String` object

To understand about strings and equality, read [String comparison with equals and assignment operator](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/27/string-comparison-with-equals-and-assignment-operator/) It will help you understand the concept well.

Comment: @MarounMaroun thanks for the references.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead of `==` to compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

`if(firstanswer.equals(answer2))` is what you're looking for.

`firstanswer` and `answer2` are pointers to string objects.  `==` checks to see whether the pointers are equal (whether they point to the same object), while [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) compares the contents of the two strings and returns a boolean representing whether or not the contents are equal.